# openconnect pulse and 2fa

Tags: networking, vpn, authentication, openconnect, 2-factor-authentication

I want to use openconnect instead of pulsesecure/pulseUI to connect to my company's vpn.
this was ok in the old server but in the new they have added 2FA.

I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63232539/959179 which looks promising.

so I try a very basic test:

```
echo -e "${myPasswd}\n${freshOTPcode} | sudo openconnect --protocol=pulse --passwd-on-stdin -u me@company.com <vpn server>
```

```
    Connected to <ip_address>:443
    SSL negotiation with <company vpn>
    Connected to HTTPS on <company vpn>
    Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
    **Unhandled Pulse authentication packet, or authentication failure**
    E [...]
    **Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie**
```

I cannot make anything out of it . The PulseSecure v9.1R13 connects fine to the server.

the error is the same if I use the following arguments

```
echo "myPasswd" | sudo openconnect --protocol=pulse -u me@company.com --passwd-on-stdin --token-mode=totp --token-secret=813940 <vpn server>
```

Comment: Could OpenConnect's understanding of the TOTP code and what to do with it clash with how the server expects to get that information, maybe depending on the 2FA implementation?  This setup works for me with a Pulse Secure server using [Duo](https://duo.com/docs/pulseconnect#test-your-setup) for 2FA if I give a TOTP at the "Secondary password:" input prompt, *without* specifying it as such in the openconnect call.  I can pipe that info in from stdin, but can't use either the `--token...` or `--password-on-stdin` arguments.